# Should the positioning of the external regressors change the output of arma-garch? (Possible rugarch bug/error)

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, modeling, quantitative-finance

Got an interesting issue with the rugarch package.

I noticed that when I changed the order of the external regressors, there are different values for the robust coefficient matrix. The values should be the same (respective to the ordering of the variables). However, I am getting drastically different results. At that time the model was arma(2,2) + garch(1,0).

Is this considered a normal behavior of the rugarch package?

I assume that when you change the ordering of the external regressors the output should be the same (according to the order of the regressors) ....digit by digit.

I confirmed this issue by creating a generic script that can be tested by anyone. Has anybody faced this issue before or is there post that describes the issue that I am facing?

Maybe I am going insane...for now I will look further into the documentation that our Alexios has provided

Thanks!

```
library(rugarch) 

set.seed(1) 

x1 <- rnorm(1000,5,1) 
x2 <- rnorm(1000,3,3) 

y    <- .5*(x1*x2) + rnorm(1000,1,3) 
dat  <- data.frame(x1,x2,y) 

var1 <- c("x1","x2") 
var2 <- c("x2","x1") 

# setbounds(spec)<-list(vxreg1=c(-1,1)) 
model_maker <- function(x_name){ 
  temp <- dat[,c("y",x_name)] 

  spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model      = list(model = "sGARCH", 
                                                garchOrder = c(1,0)), 

                     mean.model          = list(armaOrder = c(2,2), 
                                                external.regressors = as.matrix(temp[,x_name]), 
                                                include.mean= T), 

                     distribution.model  = "std") 

  fit         <- ugarchfit(spec = spec, data = as.matrix(temp$y),solver = "hybrid") 
  return(fit@fit$robust.matcoef)} 

model_maker(var1) 
model_maker(var2)
```

Results

```
> model_maker(var1)
                     Estimate            Std. Error                t value           Pr(>|t|)
mu     -7.538187403788707e+00 8.786973516670712e-02 -8.578821125939666e+01 0.0000000000000000
ar1     4.486422838091979e-01 6.673242425241943e-03  6.723002930512180e+01 0.0000000000000000
ar2     5.509436808922650e-01 8.689261995135296e-03  6.340511785704150e+01 0.0000000000000000
ma1    -4.229313469721094e-01 9.904526629376784e-05 -4.270081375900357e+03 0.0000000000000000
ma2    -5.909394433456913e-01 5.328845280848644e-05 -1.108944644104175e+04 0.0000000000000000
mxreg1  1.636837420433226e+00 1.860043860817216e-02  8.799993671730280e+01 0.0000000000000000
mxreg2  2.497594073093352e+00 2.935374105837549e-02  8.508605659927339e+01 0.0000000000000000
omega   1.204434970615901e+01 1.164871508782470e+00  1.033963799041478e+01 0.0000000000000000
alpha1  3.088952958748960e-09 7.706257096572960e-05  4.008369977849096e-05 0.9999680178348154
shape   2.264515398950677e+01 1.626608738905429e+02  1.392169699318415e-01 0.8892786990201700
> model_maker(var2)
                     Estimate            Std. Error                t value           Pr(>|t|)
mu     -7.877119924850585e+00 1.468654041377859e-02 -5.363495896869247e+02 0.0000000000000000
ar1     6.599347321880189e-01 1.052007357763227e-03  6.273099967581684e+02 0.0000000000000000
ar2     3.429324065506440e-01 7.290845959665856e-04  4.703602413873531e+02 0.0000000000000000
ma1    -6.161353098757911e-01 2.172817763786096e-05 -2.835651107721921e+04 0.0000000000000000
ma2    -3.961541217693775e-01 2.673334524811993e-06 -1.481872612995329e+05 0.0000000000000000
mxreg1  2.498594649158790e+00 4.725354999748145e-03  5.287633731840174e+02 0.0000000000000000
mxreg2  1.686570324631110e+00 3.061281186945296e-03  5.509361021207126e+02 0.0000000000000000
omega   1.177846519677343e+01 6.508282352389305e-01  1.809765550882921e+01 0.0000000000000000
alpha1  1.132843707658519e-06 5.435981230642132e-05  2.083972809311375e-02 0.9833735061770428
shape   1.352084437533810e+01 1.837896072265797e+01  7.356696920663922e-01 0.4619317385213701
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
So I contacted Alexios, through r-sig-finance and I forget to include fit.control... an important parameter not to be missed! However, upon further inspection I found some interesting results with the solvers.

According to the rugarch documentation:

> The “hybrid” strategy solver first tries the “solnp” solver, in
>   failing to converge then tries then “nlminb”, the “gosolnp” and
>   finally the “nloptr” solvers.

So I did a quick test to check each solver.

Here is the code:

```
library(rugarch) 
library(rugarch) 

set.seed(1) 

x1 <- rnorm(1000,5,1) 
x2 <- rnorm(1000,3,3) 

y    <- .5*(x1*x2) + rnorm(1000,1,3) 
dat  <- data.frame(x1,x2,y) 

var1   <- c("x1","x2") 
var2   <- c("x2","x1") 
solver <- c("solnp","hybrid","nlminb","lbfgs","nloptr")

# setbounds(spec)<-list(vxreg1=c(-1,1)) 
model_maker <- function(x_name,solver){ 
  temp <- dat[,c("y",x_name)] 

  spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model      = list(model = "sGARCH", 
                                                garchOrder = c(1,0)), 

                     mean.model          = list(armaOrder = c(2,2), 
                                                external.regressors = as.matrix(temp[,x_name]), 
                                                include.mean= T), 

                     distribution.model  = "std") 

  fit         <- ugarchfit(spec = spec, data = as.matrix(temp$y),solver = solver, fit.control=list(scale=1)) 
  return(fit@fit$robust.matcoef)} 
i=1
model1 <- model_maker(var1,solver[i]) 
model2 <- model_maker(var2,solver[i])

# Print the results
model1
model2

# Calculate the differences, note that the result is in the correct order, meaning that mxreg1 represents variable x1 
model1 - model2[c(1:5,7,6,8:10),]
sum(model1 - model2[c(1:5,7,6,8:10),])
```

A couple of things:

1. The variable `i` is used to control which solver is used
2. I did not run the gosolnp because that will take time for me to understand how to use it properly...I plan on messing around with it later
3. nlminb seems to be the most accurate solver...for this particular dataset
4. A common pattern that I am seeing is that the estimate of shape is off by a large margin, except for nlminb

Results: For each solver, I basically took the difference of the two matrices to see how different they were. I then took the sum of those differences. The results are shown after the conclusion. Note that hybrid gives the same result as solnp because it uses solnp first in it's strategy.

Conclusion: 
As stated in the documentation, the hybrid strategy uses solnp. This solver does not fail to converge. However, if you notice the differences between the two models, they are quite large. Take a look at the results between solnp and hybrid.

***solnp: sum of differences = -322573094***

```
#           Estimate    Std. Error       t value      Pr(>|t|)
# mu      1.738126e-01 -6.823128e-01 -2.014060e+04  0.000000e+00
# ar1    -1.563344e+00 -8.188160e-03 -1.280088e+02  5.132347e-01
# ar2     1.955544e+00 -7.682856e-03  1.155578e+03  0.000000e+00
# ma1     1.537478e+00 -1.268071e-02 -9.338894e+01  0.000000e+00
# ma2    -1.933255e+00 -1.065511e-05 -3.225948e+08  0.000000e+00
# mxreg1 -8.917738e-02 -1.263512e-01  2.067577e+04  0.000000e+00
# mxreg2 -8.266427e-03 -4.321936e-02  2.033637e+04  0.000000e+00
# omega   1.866515e-02  9.641896e-03 -4.654283e-01  0.000000e+00
# alpha1  2.971507e-12  5.501971e-06  1.915043e-07 -1.527983e-07
# shape  -2.869267e+01 -2.406363e+01  1.578825e+00 -8.739897e-02
```

***hybrid: sum of differences = -322573094***

```
#            Estimate    Std. Error       t value      Pr(>|t|)
# mu      1.738126e-01 -6.823128e-01 -2.014060e+04  0.000000e+00
# ar1    -1.563344e+00 -8.188160e-03 -1.280088e+02  5.132347e-01
# ar2     1.955544e+00 -7.682856e-03  1.155578e+03  0.000000e+00
# ma1     1.537478e+00 -1.268071e-02 -9.338894e+01  0.000000e+00
# ma2    -1.933255e+00 -1.065511e-05 -3.225948e+08  0.000000e+00
# mxreg1 -8.917738e-02 -1.263512e-01  2.067577e+04  0.000000e+00
# mxreg2 -8.266427e-03 -4.321936e-02  2.033637e+04  0.000000e+00
# omega   1.866515e-02  9.641896e-03 -4.654283e-01  0.000000e+00
# alpha1  2.971507e-12  5.501971e-06  1.915043e-07 -1.527983e-07
# shape  -2.869267e+01 -2.406363e+01  1.578825e+00 -8.739897e-02
```

***nlminb: sum of differences = 0.004690549***

```
#           Estimate    Std. Error       t value      Pr(>|t|)
# mu      8.334588e-06 -6.810307e-07  1.505486e-06  0.000000e+00
# ar1     8.212314e-06 -1.753588e-06  1.858127e-04 -3.444543e-08
# ar2    -1.410239e-06 -1.691983e-06 -3.677855e-04  0.000000e+00
# ma1    -8.903242e-06 -2.680788e-06 -2.087611e-04 -5.599837e-07
# ma2    -6.084540e-07  1.463211e-06 -2.847722e-04  0.000000e+00
# mxreg1 -1.707573e-06 -2.549609e-07  1.286915e-05  0.000000e+00
# mxreg2 -1.228276e-07 -1.125697e-08  1.254835e-05  0.000000e+00
# omega   4.556487e-06  1.505588e-04 -2.618454e-03  0.000000e+00
# alpha1  0.000000e+00  2.212422e-05  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
# shape   9.509008e-04  6.844028e-03 -3.480029e-05  2.262813e-05
```

***lbfgs:*** failed to converge

***nloptr: sum of differences = 9.937713***

```
#             Estimate    Std. Error      t value     Pr(>|t|)
# mu     -0.0057978361 -1.525932e-04 -0.010722941  0.000000000
# ar1     0.0007429396 -1.984846e-02 -0.018458177 -0.009827180
# ar2     0.0010449391 -7.694273e-03 -0.017611750 -0.008069019
# ma1    -0.0007444894 -1.894543e-02  0.019331928 -0.009721757
# ma2    -0.0007670455 -7.811075e-03  0.021252924 -0.008391716
# mxreg1  0.0013125601 -2.700489e-05  0.012942836  0.000000000
# mxreg2  0.0000503455 -5.738682e-06  0.008939747  0.000000000
# omega  -0.0003911163 -1.940285e-04  0.002957193  0.000000000
# alpha1  0.0000000000 -3.453686e-05  0.000000000  0.000000000
# shape   1.0873917654  8.931931e+00 -0.017380270  0.012411900
```

Comment: UPDATE 2:  It seems that I have to fine tune the parameters manually. Gonna have to mess around with fit.control = list(scale = 0),solver.control = list(tol=1e-15,delta=1e-15)

Comment: The source is from https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2011q4/008882.html

Comment: `fit.control` does not seem to change anything as of 2019 concerning the robust coefficients, the documentation says `The scale parameter controls whether the data should be scaled...`

Comment: leaving out the ar and ma orders and the mean yields a much better minimum working example

Comment: Alexios may have updated the package to scale the data by default if there you do not see any major differences. Not sure what you mean by better minimum working example. The example I provided pinpoints the issue I found. I'll double check later to see if the updates affect the results shown here.