# rugarch gives two different results based on the same model...how is that even possible?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, modeling, finance

Recently I have discovered a problem with a package called rugarch that creates arma-garch models. The issue is that if you literally change the positions of the x variables (external regressors)  then you get two completely different results.

In other words:

- model1 = (arma(2,2) + garch(1,0) + x1 + x2)
- model2 = (arma(2,2) + garch(1,0) + x2 + x1)
- rugarch's output is essentially saying that model1 != model2
- When the correct result should be model1 == model2

I may not know a lot of statistics but I know for a fact that if you move the x variables around, the output should still be the same.

Am I wrong on this?

Here's my stack exchange post that shows a generic R script proving my point: [Should the positioning of the external regressors change the output of arma-garch? (Possible rugarch bug/error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900177/should-the-positioning-of-the-external-regressors-change-the-output-of-arma-garc)

I will admit that this post is somewhat of a duplicate but I think people may have the wrong idea of what I'm trying to convey so I created this post to clarify my point.

Any feedback is welcomed.

Thanks